# disk usage unit sufix for size (du utility)

Tags: disk-usage

what unit does `E` stand for in `du`? For example:

```
16E
```

when using:

```
du -h
```

*ps. I have K (kilo) and M (mega) and **this couldn't be exa!**

[image]

Comment: This looks like some kind of overflow condition.  Consider submitting a bug report to the author.

Comment: `ls -l /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots` ?

Comment: @AlexP - you don't want that :) 3.3gb of 500kb files

Comment: @ceph3us: And one or more sparse files with large apparent sizes, maybe?

Comment: @AlexP no i tar and moved whole folder without problem and there is none of an irregular file other as jpg - i think is just  some buffer overflow in this version of du

Comment: What do you see with `du -k` instead of `du -h`?

Answer (score 4):

16E does mean 16 exabytes, or more precisely 16 [exbibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) (16 EiB), i.e. 16·1024<sup>6</sup> bytes. This is 2<sup>64</sup> bytes. 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (which is within the 3-digit precision of the displayed value) is the maximum value that can be represented in a “native” variable on a 64-bit system.

Many programs use native variables to store integers either between 0 and 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (unsigned integer) or between -2<sup>63</sup> and 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (signed integer). The representation in memory of the signed integer -*x* is the same as the representation of the unsigned integer 2<sup>64</sup>-*x*. For 32-bit systems, the intervals are 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (4 GiB) and -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, respectively.

You mention that the `Screenshots` directory contains about 3.3 GiB. Observe that this is more than the maximum signed 32-bit value, but less than the maximum unsigned 32-bit value. What likely happened here is that some part of the system stored the size in a 32-bit variable, then converted the value to 64-bit, but interpreted the value as signed rather than unsigned. So a value about -0.7 GiB (on a scale of -2 GiB to 2 GiB) got converted to -0.7 GiB (on a scale of -16 EiB to 16 EiB). 16 EiB - 0.7 GiB is 16 EiB (up to about 9 decimal digits of precision).

This is a bug in the part of the system that used 32-bit values. If you put 4.1 GiB in that directory, you'll get a total size of ~0.1 GiB — differently wrong, for the same reason. Check the bug tracker for the operating system you're running, and if you don't find that bug, report it.

Answer (score 1):

from man page

SIZE may be (or may be an integer optionally followed by) one of following: KB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, and so on  for  G, T, P, E, Z, Y.

so, it should be giga tera peta exa zetta yotta

Comment: exa falls - as there could be max  few GB - maybe du couldn't  handle too many files ???

Comment: what is the output of df -h

Comment: this folder got 3,3gb - i think the amount of files is issue here  :)